# Clustering of multi-instance service based on hibernate

Tags: web-services, hibernate, caching, hazelcast

I have developed service uses hibernate to talk with Database whose instances are running on multiple servers and at other end i have web application that requests randomly to service instances. In practical run i am facing problem due presence of stale cached entities at service instance.

Is there any framework that can help me to sync hibernate caches at services. I tried with Hazelcast, but won't help !

Comment: what was the problem with hazelcast?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is solution for you:

http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/rmi-replicated-caching